# Changing IDE shortcuts in Code::Blocks

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, codeblocks

I'd like to change Build, Debug & Run shortcut keys in Code::Blocks. Does any know a plugin or setting to change the keys?

Answer (score 13):

From the menu it's under settings->editor->keyboard shortcuts (might need to scroll down). Configure whatever shortcut keys you need on the right-hand side.

Comment: @EdwardBird which version of C::B are you using? Can you go under `Manage plugins` and see if "Keyboard shortcuts" plugin is installed?

Comment: Nope I don't have that! (V:12.11)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib` ... Why didn't I know about this before?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Open CodeBlocks
> 2. Click on Settings
> 3. Go to Editor

- Refer to these 3 screenshots

[image: selecting settings and editor]

> 4. That opens Configure editor
> 5. There select the Keyboard shortcuts
> 6. In commands select Edit

[image: 2]

> 7. Scroll down and find the comment
> 8. There you can customize your keyboard shortcut and click on add

[image: final step]

> 9. don't forget to click on ok.

There all the keyboard shortcuts are available and you can play with them.

For better and easy understanding refer to the screenshots because one image tells  1000 sentences.
This should work else let me know.

Hare Krishna!!!